# Collect all redirected URL of Origin URL using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, express, redirect

I want to retrieve a list of urls that are redirected from Origin URL X and it may have many redirected URLs but i want all list of it.

For example:

```
http://www.example.com/origin-url
```

It will redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/first-redirect
```

Again it will redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/second-redicect
```

And finally it goes to this

```
http://www.example.com/final-url
```

So what i want is list of all this URLs using **NodeJs or Express**

```
 http://www.example.com/origin-url -->> http://www.example.com/first-redirect
 -->> http://www.example.com/second-redicect -->> http://www.example.com/final-url
```

Give me suggestion for this and which node module should i have to use to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `http` module of NodeJS. You will need to check the `statusCode`, which for redirect is between 300-400. Please look at the below code.

```
    var http = require('http')


    function listAllRedirectURL(path) {
      var reqPath = path;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var redirectArr = [];

        function get(reqPath, cb){
            http.get({
              hostname: 'localhost',
              port: 3000,
              path: reqPath,
              agent: false  // create a new agent just for this one request
            }, (res) => {
              cb(res)
            }); 
        }

        function callback(res) {
            if (res.headers.hasOwnProperty('location') && res.statusCode >= 300 && res.statusCode < 400) {
               console.log(res.headers.location);
               redirectArr.push(res.headers.location);
               reqPath = (res.headers.location);
               get(reqPath, callback);
            } else {
              resolve(redirectArr);
            }
        }

        get(reqPath, callback);
      })
    }

    listAllRedirectURL('/');
```

Comment: But here i dont know the hostname and port for the url which i will get from previous redirection so for that ??

Comment: I have given a example where redirection is done on the different path of the same host. So that, you can append the host to every element of the `redirectArr`.

Comment: What if i want to redirect url using VPN for specific country ?? Any idea ??